# Minimal delta between Docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**Problem:** 
I am trying to determine whether a Docker image built after changing the Dockerfile ever so slightly - say just by adding in the following:

*RUN echo 'we are running xyz*

Does this result in a completely different Docker image than an image where we change out the underlying OS?

**Objective:** I do realize the digest of the images will be different in both cases - but my objective is to build totally different image with the most minimal difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

IF your Dockerfile change adds a new layer, however small it is, the result will be a different image.

Your change will be visible in [docker image history](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_history/) (docker 1.13, before it was `docker history`). or for published images in [`imagelayers.io`](https://imagelayers.io/).

Comment: Thanks. What is the tiniest layer one could add in a Docker image to accomplish this goal? Preferably something trivial.

Comment: Try something whic does not involve adding/copying files: `USER` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/user), or `WORKDIR` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/workdir)